# How to make a pageViewController scroll automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `pageViewController` and I want to make it change with its pages automatically. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to turn pages without user's interaction?

Comment: I want both, pages turn automatically and user can turn pages, just like App Store's banners.

Comment: you can use timer to achieve this

Comment: @AnilKumar How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` in the timer code